# temporary store multiple rows data and display in table from user input(client side)

Tags: json, jsp, servlets

I want to store temporary Multiple rows and Columns Data and Display Into Table from user Input(Client side). After this process Execution Click on Submit Button save All Table Data into Database(Mysql).

Answer (score 0):

first, Display Data

```
<table>
  <% for (int i=0; i < len; i++) { 
       Object obj = list.get(i);
   ... 
  %>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<%=obj.name%>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="addr" value="<%=obj.addr%>"></td>
    </tr>
  <% } //end of for loop.. %>
</table>
```

Second, User change this values...

Finally, You can get this all value like this and save all

```
 String[] names = request.getParameterValues("name");
 String[] addrs = request.getParameterValues("addr");
 int len = names == null ? 0 : names.length;
 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     stmt.setString(1, names[i]);
     stmt.setString(2, addrs[i]);
     stmt.executeUpdate();
 }
 conn.commit();
 ....
```

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: thanks Seoul, but I have one Form ,Multiple Button and One Submit Which Submit Button is being used for Save All Data in the database. Before This process I use Button Which Add No. Rows Data in the table.